# Exception When Jetty Server Started Remotely- java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

Tags: jetty, webdriver

I am fairly new to Jetty and Servlet. Sorry if this sounds really basic. I am using jetty 6.1.22,jetty-util-6.1.22 and Selenium 2.0b2.
I am trying to configure the selenium server in the code so that I can avoid the manual process of starting the selenium
server on the remote host. The wiki[1] notes say- "In theory, the process is as simple as mapping the "DriverServlet" to a URL,
but it's also possible to host the page in a lightweight container, such as Jetty configured entirely in code"

**[Edit#1]**

Here is what I have so far, basically copy of the code from the RemoteWebDriverServer wiki [1].

If I set the remote host like below, I get bind exception.

```
public AppServer() throws Exception { 
        try {
            WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext(); 
            context.setContextPath(""); 
            context.setWar("."); 
            server.addHandler(context); 
            context.addServlet(DriverServlet.class, "/wd/*"); 
            SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector(); 
            connector.setHost("MyRemoteHostIPAddress");
            connector.setPort(4444); 
            server.addConnector(connector); 
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      } 
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
              new AppServer(); 
      } 
}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
2011-06-06 14:39:02.618:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-06-06 14:39:02.633:INFO::jetty-6.1.22
2011-06-06 14:39:02.977:WARN::failed SelectChannelConnector@MyRemoteHostIPAddress:4444: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
2011-06-06 14:39:02.977:WARN::failed Server@b61fd1: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:315)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at AppServer.main(AppServer.java:31)
```

**[Edit#2]**

**Please disregard my first two comments below. I edited the question.**

Is there anything I am missing or doing incorrectly?

Thanks,
-Nilesh

[1]http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer

Comment: Please disregard the second Exception I posted earlier, I fixed that. 
It turned out to be a bug in my code. So when I run start the jetty 
server through code "locally" on the "remote" host, I was actually 
connecting from my local machine to URL http://remoteServer:remotePort/wd/hub 
instead of http://remoteServer:remotePort/wd. After this change test 
works fine. 
The only issue that I have now is- how to start the server "remotely" 
from my "local" machine. Following still seems to be a problem. 
Anyone? 
connector.setHost("MyRemoteHostIPAddress"); 
connector.setPort(3002);

Comment: Here is the part of stack trace when I use connector.setHost("MyRemoteHostIPAddress"); SelectChannelConnector@MyRemoteHostIPAddress:3002: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
failed Server@b61fd1: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is in line:

```
 connector.setHost("MyRemoteHostIPAddress");
```

Try to replace `"MyRemoteHostIPAddress"` with `"localhost"`, or direct IP.

Comment: It does not work either